# Non abelian subgroup of a abelian group.

Tags: abelian-groups

What is the relationship between abelian subgroup of a  non-abelian group(when exist, example, theorem)?? any thing such link regarding the question would help.

```
 I apologize for previous post-error.
```

Comment: How can you lose commutivity? Did you perhaps mean the abelian subgroup of a non-abelian group?

Comment: You can have abelian subgroups in a non-abelian group, but not non-abelian subgroups in an abelian group.

Comment: Another way of saying that it is not possible is that the class of abelian groups forms a variety, and therefore is closed under taking subalgebras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the other way around. I mean, it is possible for a subgroup of **noncommutative** group to be **commutative**: just take any nonabelian group $G$ (for example $S_5 \times \mathbb Z_{24}$) and look at its center, the set of elements that commute with everything, $Z(G) := \{g \in G : (\forall h \in G)(hg=gh)\}$ (in this example: $Z(G) = \{e\} \times Z_{24}$).

Comment: nice example!!!

Answer (score 12):

If $H$ is a subgroup of an abelian group, and $x,y \in H$ then $x,y \in G$ and hence 
$$xy=yx$$