# Can non-abelian subgroups be found in abelian groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I am aware that abelian-subgroups can be found in non-abelian groups. All one must do is consider $gp(\{x\})$.

However, this had me wondering if the other way around was true. I couldn't find anything on the forum that asked this… so here's hoping someone could shed some insight.

If the answer is **no**, it is sort of interesting because, in a hand-wavey way, I interpret this as meaning that a non-abelian subgroup effectively "taints" the overarching group, stripping it of the ability to be abelian.

This makes me wonder why abelian subgroups do **not** taint non-abelian groups from being non-abelian. Why does the “abelian property” behave so sensitively while the “non-abelian property” does not?

Comment: How could that possibly work.  If $a,b \in G \subset H$ and $H$ is abelian then $a*b =b*a$ so $G$ is abelian.  Nothing to do with tainting.

Comment: In the jargon, we'd say that abelian-ness is a [*hereditary property*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditary_property) of groups.

Comment: "I couldn't find anything on the forum that asked this" - I could - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140909/non-abelian-subgroup-of-a-abelian-group).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is negative: If $G$ is an Abelian group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $H$ is Abelian too. In fact, since$$(\forall g_1,g_2\in G):g_1g_2=g_2g_1,$$then, in particular,$$(\forall g_1,g_2\in H):g_1g_2=g_2g_1.$$

And note that being Abelian means that something *always* occurs. And being non-Abelian means that that thing *sometimes* doesn't occur. For such a property, it is clear that if a group has it, every subgroup also has it, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

How could that possibly work?

If $a,b \in G \subset H$ and $H$ is abelian then $a*b =b*a$ so $G$ is abelian.

The "tainting" issue should be obvious.  If $X$ is a  condition that SomethingCanBeSaidAboutEveryElement (or pair of elements) it'd be inheritable by subsets as the elements of subset are subsets of the original.  But if $X$ is an "anti" condition that it isn't true for all elements it takes just one counter example to achieve this.  It need not be inherited by a subset that avoids the counter issue. But supersets will inherrit it.

It's like being sick.. An organ is healthy if none of its components is sick.  So if a body is healthy it has no sick components.  So none of the components are sick.  But if you have one sick cell you are not healthy but if you take a component that excludes the cell that may be healthy.  But every component using that cell will be sick.

Or being .... blue.  If we say a set is Blue if all its elements are blue, but a set is NotBlue if at least one element is not blue then.....

Or... maybe I dont understand your question.

Comment: I guess I thought of the physical concept of "emergent properties" and wondered if there was some sort of mathematical equivalent. In this particular instance, I thought, "hmmmm, well, at the small level, abelian properties are not present...but at a large scale level, maybe abelian properties ARE present".

Comment: But "abelianness" is a global property.  Either every it applies to every pair of elements.  Or the group isn't abelian.  This... isn't philosophy.  It's just common sense.  A community is smoke free if no-one smokes.  It's tainted if a single person smokes.  If a country is smoke free it passes down to it's districts, counties, cities, neighbor hoods, streets and houses.  But if there is a smoker nothing including it is smoke free.  But it's nextdoor neighbor maybe.  No philosophy.

Comment: Well, I don't know if emergent properties are "philosophy" (they are literally used to describe chemical systems, biology, etc), but I understand your point. Cheers~